# Multiple try catch php Database

Tags: php, exception, database-connection, try-catch

So what I'm trying to do is have one try catch on a single page. The reason for being so is that the server that I'm running my code on doesn't seem to like multiple try catches. So I was wondering what exactly I should insert into my code to catch the database connection errors as well as the query errors.  My code's a little long for this page, so I've tried to shorten it out as much as possible and still have all of my try catches in there. The error page works perfectly fine. I feel like my only issue is the placement of the catches

This is what I've got so far...

```
try{

    $db = @mysqli_connect('xxxx', 'xxxx', 'xxxx', 'xxxx');

        if(!$db){
        throw new aException(mysqli_connect_error());  
    }

    $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM blah blah blah";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $strSQL);
    if(!$result){
        throw new bException(mysqli_error($db));  
    }

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    echo '<select name="customer">';
    $custSQL = "select blah blah blah";
    $rs=mysqli_query($db,$custSQL);
    if(!$rs){
        throw new cException(mysqli_error($db));  
    }
     while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($rs)){ 

        if($row['cust_id'] == $customer){

            echo '<option selected="selected" value="'.$row[2].'">'.$row['cust_fname']. " " .$row['cust_lname'].'</option>';
        }
        else{
            echo '<option value="'.$row[2].'">'.$row['cust_fname']. " " .$row['cust_lname'].'</option>';
    }

        }

    mysqli_close($db);
    unset($db);

}catch(aException $e){ 

    header("Location: error.php?msg=" . $e->getMessage() . "&line=" . $e->getLine());
}
catch(bException $e){ 

    header("Location: error.php?msg=" . $e->getMessage() . "&line=" . $e->getLine());
}
catch(cException $e){ 

    header("Location: error.php?msg=" . $e->getMessage() . "&line=" . $e->getLine());
}
```

Comment: you seem to already have them? `throw new whatever` is the code to throw a exception. so `catch whatever` picks it up.

Comment: Well I've got several more exceptions that are identical to the first 3 and this is the error I get when I change something up in the code for the exception "Fatal error: Class 'fException' not found in /www/virtualhosts/www.wat.com/group4/editorder2.php on line 209"

Comment: @elephantCoder , Are these custom exceptions?

Comment: you need to extend Exception with fException (this is one you added yourself to existing code?)

Comment: no, I just added the aException, bException, cException, because I thought throwing a new exception had to be named different

Comment: no exception is a global, but if you are nesting trys within catchs, its handy to have all exceptions not just the last. But @sectus is after giving you a good way to differentiate them.

Answer (score 0):

You could use interface while creating exceptions.

```
interface myExceptionInterface{}

class aException extends \Exception implements myExceptionInterface {}
class bException extends \Exception implements myExceptionInterface {}
class cException extends \Exception implements myExceptionInterface {}
```

And catch it using this interface.

```
try{
    throw new bException;
}catch(myExceptionInterface $e){ 
    header("Location: error.php?msg=" . $e->getMessage() . "&line=" . $e->getLine());
}
```

P.S. throwing and catching exceptions in the same scope smells.

Comment: alright so I tried it and got a 500 Internal server error! should I post my entire code on here? because I'm not so sure what the myExceptionInterface does and I know I'm not adding it right in my code

Comment: You should explore your errors. Try to find error.log of your web server.